# Can stellar wind cause a star to have a Bimodial Radiation spectrum?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, astrophysics, thermal-radiation, stellar-wind

Most stars emit Stellar wind, so more then others.
Some stars such as [Eta Carinae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eta_Carinae) emit enough stellar wind (0.001 solar masses a year) that most of the radiation they emit will be absorbed and re-emitted by the stellar wind, hiding the true surface of the star making their sizes difficult to define.

Is it possible, if given a slightly less extreme to have a star where the emission spectrum has two peaks due to most (but no where near all) of the radiation being absorbed and re-emitted by the solar wind?